# NPE On AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-alertdialog

my app is crashing when i try to push the buttons of the `AlertDialog`.

```
public void lalalal(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm Delete...");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want delete this?");

    // Setting Icon to Dialog
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_ic);

    // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

            // Write your code here to invoke YES event
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // Setting Negative "NO" Button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Write your code here to invoke NO event
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You clicked on NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();

}
```

I am completty stumped as to why this would happen.!.. Been looking at this for ages..

As for the Error Logg:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:105)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:261)
        at android.android.startingpoint.dp.test.ListHistoryFragment$2.onClick(ListHistoryFragment.java:138)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:185)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post class `Toast`

Comment: which one is `ListHistoryFragment$2.onClick(ListHistoryFragment.java:138)`?

Comment: @AlexR Toast is part of the android framework

Comment: `            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` is the 138th line

Comment: What does `getActivity()` return?

Comment: How is `getActivity()` implemented?

Comment: I thought `getActivity()` was used to access the parent Activity.. so i did, anyhow i dont really know how to go about this, since the alertdialog is located in a fragment..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that when you show the `Dialog`, your `Fragment` gets detached from the `Activity`, which means `getActivity()` will return null. You may want to review the [Fragment lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle) to understand how they can be attached and detached to their parent Activity.

*One* way to get around this is to use the `Context` reference that the `Dialog` maintains:

```
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
        Toast.makeText(((Dialog) dialogInterface).getContext(), "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

// Setting Negative "NO" Button
alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Toast.makeText(((Dialog) dialogInterface).getContext(), "You clicked on NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I viewed some version of `Toast` in grepcode and guess that you `getActivity()` returns `null`.

You call `makeToast()` that calls constructor of `Toast()`. The second line of the constructor looks like:

```
    mTN.mY 
=context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(com.android.internal.R.dimen.toast_y_offset);
```

that will definitely produce NPE if `context` (activity in this case) is `null`.

Comment: Very interesting to know reason for downvoting very reasonable answer.